# how to download torrent files with remote ubuntu server via ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, bittorrent

how to download torrent files with remote ubuntu server via ssh?

I've tried using bittorrent but when I turn off putty the download process also stops

Comment: If you want to use an interactive ascii client, you can use screen or byobu to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move a process into the background with the `&` operator in Bash.

For example, to run some Python process in the background:

```
$ python somefile.py &
```

So you can run whatever torrent client you're using in the background by adding a `&` at the end.